# Google API get all logged in accounts

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm using `Google API Javascript SDK` to get access token, then submit the token to server. On server side, I use `Google API PHP Client` to get user info by access token, if I logged in 3 accounts then I just get information of the first one.

How can I get data of all logged in accounts?

Here is the PHP Code command I used:

```
$google_user = Google_Client::getUserInfo($accessToken);
```

*$accessToken* is gotten and submitted by Javascript SDK

**-- Edit on May 18th, 2015 --**
For example, I logged in 3 accounts *myemail1@gmail.com*, *myemail2@gmail.com* and *myemail3@gmail.com*. My website have *myemail2@gmail.com* as login email address. With the code snippet above, I just get `$google_user` is *myemail1@gmail.com*.

Comment: You should probably be sending the Refresh Token if you want to be able to access them later.   You cant get a Refresh Token with JavaScript.

Comment: @DaImTo: that's not what I means. For example, I logged in 3 accounts myemail1@gmail.com, myemail2@gmail.com and myemail3@gmail.com. My website have myemail2@gmail.com as login email address. With the code snippet above, I just get <code>$google_user</code> is myemail1@gmail.com.

Comment: well yes that's because accesstoken is going to relate back to a single user.  Each user / email address that has granted you access will have its own access token.  Its going to be up to you to save access tokens  for all longed in accounts  which again is pointless as Access tokens are only good for about an hour.  You need to be saving everyone's refresh token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO api that will return a list of all the accounts that have logged into your application.

It is up to you as a developer to keep track of each of the users as they access your application.  If you want to access them again later you will need to save everyone's refresh token.   access tokens are short lived and will expire.